# Is using an await sleep(ms) function the best way to add a delay between a write file and read file function in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am trying to implement the following flow in my code:

1. Get request comes in with filename in the parameter.
2. Nodejs makes a call to was s3 bucket to retrieve the file that is requested.
3. The file is retrieved and saved.
4. The file is read and sent back in the response.

Here is my /get endpoint:

```
router.get('/getPDF/:fileName', async (req, res, next) => {
  const key = req.params.fileName
  console.log(key)
  console.log(key.toString())
  const goodKey = key + '.pdf'
  console.log(goodKey)
  const saveToFile = 'currentPDF.pdf'
  getFileAndSave(goodKey, saveToFile)

  await sleep(1000);
  const data = await fs.readFileSync('./s3Storage/currentPDF.pdf');
  res.contentType("application/pdf");
  res.send(data)
});
```

This is the getFileandSave function:

```
const getFileAndSave = async (key, filename) => {
var params = {
  Bucket: BUCKET_NAME, 
  Key: key
};
console.log(key)
let readStream = await s3.getObject(params).createReadStream();
let writeStream = await fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, filename));
await readStream.pipe(writeStream);
return key
}
```

I am currently using a sleep function to add a delay, but there must be a better way to do this.

Comment: getFileAndSave should return a promise and you should wait for it to resolve in your /get endpoint

Answer (score 0):

```
router.get('/getPDF/:fileName', async (req, res, next) => {
  const key = req.params.fileName
  console.log(key)
  console.log(key.toString())
  const goodKey = key + '.pdf'
  console.log(goodKey)
  const saveToFile = 'currentPDF.pdf'
  let file = await getFileAndSave(goodKey, saveToFile)

  const data = await fs.readFileSync('./s3Storage/currentPDF.pdf');
  res.contentType("application/pdf");
  res.send(data)
});
const getFileAndSave = async (key, filename) => {
 return new Promise((resolve) => {
var params = {
  Bucket: BUCKET_NAME, 
  Key: key
};
console.log(key)
let readStream = await s3.getObject(params).createReadStream();
let writeStream = await fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, filename));
await readStream.pipe(writeStream);
resolve(key);
})
}
```

Yes well advised by aymcg31
check above modified code. Please test and mark the answer appropriately thanks.